# Ruby native C big integer segfault

Tags: c, ruby

I'm working on a Ruby native C method: power mod. Here's what I got:

```
#define TO_BIGNUM(x) (FIXNUM_P(x) ? rb_int2big(FIX2LONG(x)) : x)
#define CONST2BIGNUM(x) (TO_BIGNUM(INT2NUM(x)))

VALUE method_big_power_mod(VALUE self, VALUE base, VALUE exp, VALUE mod){
  VALUE res = TO_BIGNUM(INT2NUM(1));

  base = TO_BIGNUM(base);
  exp = TO_BIGNUM(exp);
  mod = TO_BIGNUM(mod);

  while (rb_big_cmp(exp, CONST2BIGNUM(0))) {
    if (rb_big_modulo(exp, CONST2BIGNUM(2))) {
      VALUE mul = rb_big_mul(res, base);
      res = rb_big_modulo(mul, mod);
    }
    base = rb_big_modulo(rb_big_pow(base, CONST2BIGNUM(2)), mod);
    exp = rb_big_div(exp, CONST2BIGNUM(2));
  }

  return res;
}
```

It segfaults every time. I isolated the problem to `rb_big_modulo` calls. gdb stacktrace says that it crashes in the `bigdivrem` method after calling `rb_big_modulo`. I tried to look through the source of `bignum.c`, but I can't figure out what's causing the crash. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you add enough code to make this a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems that are causing the segfault:

1 - The functions `rb_big_*` sometimes doesn't return a `Bignum` object, but when you call then the first arg **must** be a `Bignum` object. For example:

```
if (rb_big_modulo(exp, CONST2BIGNUM(2))) {
  VALUE mul = rb_big_mul(res, base); // This maybe return a Fixnum 
  res = rb_big_modulo(mul, mod); // This will cause a segfault :(
}
```

2 - The function `rb_big_pow` when you call it with both args `Bignum`, it will warn you and will return a `Float` object where you can't convert easily to a `Bignum` object. So, you should replace the line where you call it by:

```
VALUE x = TO_BIGNUM(rb_big_pow(base, INT2NUM(2))); // Power by a Fixnum instead a Bignum
base = TO_BIGNUM(rb_big_modulo(x , mod));
```

The final implementation will be:

```
#define TO_BIGNUM(x) (FIXNUM_P(x) ? rb_int2big(FIX2LONG(x)) : x)
#define CONST2BIGNUM(x) (TO_BIGNUM(INT2NUM(x)))

VALUE method_big_power_mod(VALUE self, VALUE base, VALUE exp, VALUE mod){
  VALUE res = TO_BIGNUM(INT2NUM(1));

  base = TO_BIGNUM(base);
  exp = TO_BIGNUM(exp);
  mod = TO_BIGNUM(mod);

  while (rb_big_cmp(exp, CONST2BIGNUM(0))) {
    if (rb_big_modulo(exp, CONST2BIGNUM(2))) {
      VALUE mul = TO_BIGNUM(rb_big_mul(res, base));
      res = TO_BIGNUM(rb_big_modulo(mul, mod));
    }
    VALUE x = TO_BIGNUM(rb_big_pow(base, INT2NUM(2)));

    base = TO_BIGNUM(rb_big_modulo(x , mod));
    exp = TO_BIGNUM(rb_big_div(exp, CONST2BIGNUM(2)));
  }

  return res;
}
```

I don't know the performance impact with all these conversions. Maybe, you should test when it is a `Fixnum` or a `Bignum`and calculate it using the proper function or benchmark both approaches.

When I ran it, I went thought an infinite loop, but I don't know if I call it with the correct values.